# Переход из ExpandableListView в WebView по нажатию на элемент в группе

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытался сделать при нажатии на элемент в ExpandableListView открывать WebView.
Раньше я использовал ListView и там можно было сделать так

Код из ListView

```
public class activity_stigmata_detail_4 extends ListActivity {
private String titles[] = {            "несколько элементов",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail_4);


    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(activity_stigmata_detail_4.this, activity_stigmata_detail_4_view.class);

            intent.putExtra("title", position);


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Код из WebView

```java
public class activity_stigmata_detail_4_view extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail_4_view);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String resName = "q" + intent.getIntExtra("mSpringMonthsArray", 0);
    Log.i("name", resName);
    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст


    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
            "raw", "....."));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}


private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

И вот что я пытался сделать в ExpanableListView

```java
public class activity_stigmata_detail extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mGroupsArray = new String[]{"несколько элементов",};

private String[] mWinterMonthsArray = new String[]{"несколько элементов",};
private String[] mSpringMonthsArray = new String[]{"несколько элементов",};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Stigmata");

    Map <String, String> map;

    ArrayList <Map <String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList <>();


    for (String group : mGroupsArray) {

        map = new HashMap <>();
        map.put("groupName", group); 
        groupDataList.add(map);
    }


    String groupFrom[] = new String[]{"groupName"};

    int groupTo[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};


    ArrayList <ArrayList <Map <String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList <>();

    // в итоге получится сhildDataList = ArrayList<сhildDataItemList>


    ArrayList <Map <String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList <>();

    for (String month : mWinterMonthsArray) {
        map = new HashMap <>();
        map.put("monthName", month);
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
    }

    сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);


    сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList <>();
    for (String month : mSpringMonthsArray) {
        map = new HashMap <>();
        map.put("monthName", month);
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
    }
    сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);



    String childFrom[] = new String[]{"monthName"};

    int childTo[] = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupDataList,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom, childTo);

    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(activity_stigmata_detail.this, activity_stigmata_detail_4_view.class);

            intent.putExtra("mSpringMonthsArray", childPosition);

            return false;

        }


    });
}
}
```

Но код в expanableListView не работает,элементы не реагируют на нажатия

Comment: Вы забыли дописать `startActivity(intent);` в обработчике.

Comment: Да спасибо),)))